# Change the display name of the Title column in a ContentType, wise or not?

Tags: sharepoint

I once read, that it is not wise to change the display name of the Title column, when creating a new ContentType in SharePoint. It is however possible (i.e. the columns static name is still "Title" but the display name is "Description").

So my question is, what are the possible complications? Why shouln't I change it, when I create a new ContentType that needs a "Description" column but no "Title" column?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I agree that you need to do this with the CAML XML.  I just wanted to post the actual details of how to do it so that the next person with this question doesn't have to continue searching like I did.  Thanks to [Lambros's Blog](http://spandothers.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/renaming-the-title-column-in-a-sharepoint-list/) for the answer.

You actually need to update three fields -- the title field and the two calculated fields based on it and you need to use the predefined SharePoint ID values.  See below or the link above:

You need to add to the FieldRefs by adding the following:

```
<FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" DisplayName="Renamed" Sealed="TRUE"/>
<FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" ID="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" DisplayName="Renamed" Sealed="TRUE"/>
<FieldRef Name="Title" ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" DisplayName="Renamed" Sealed="TRUE"/>
```

You need to add to the Fields by adding the following:

```
<Field Name="LinkTitle" ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" DisplayName="Renamed" Sealed="TRUE" Type="Calculated"/>
<Field Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" ID="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" DisplayName="Renamed" Sealed="TRUE" Type="Calculated"/>
<Field Name="Title" ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" DisplayName="Renamed" Sealed="TRUE" Type="Text"/>
```

That should do it.  Thanks again to Lambros.

Comment: Will this rename the field for the particular content type that references this fields or for the whole site? +1.

Answer (score 9):

If you're developing your own content type as xml-files in a feature in a solution, then there is no problem changing the display name of the title column.

The problem is when users try do it through the UI.

1. They go to  site settings/Content types
2. Open the content type and clicks the title column
3. Change the name to something nice

In that case what they're changing is the display name of the Title Site Column. And once they discover that it changed the title column in all lists, they try to change it back, but this is prevented by the clever SharePoint UI bacause Title is a reserved name.

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand. I want to create my content type as xml in Visual Studio, so I'm save. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I have first-hand experience with your question of "what are the possible complications", so let me give you a specific example that I just ran into which is causing me a lot of pain this morning.

You inadvertanly change the site column name (thinking that you're only affecting a specific list), but then later realize you have change the parent item site column, and checked the nifty box that said to apply to all inherited content types.  (I feel like bull-whipping myself for this...ugh).

So all your lists were affected, sure.  But wait, there's more pain to be had here.  The internal SharePoint people list, referred to as "User Information List" is also affected, and you can't change it back to the original "Name" column title.  Where this will really nail you is when you try to connect to SharePoint lists via Microsoft Access, which is hard-coded to lookup the user information list specifically looking for the column named, "Name".  Hence, it breaks these linked lists making them useless via MS Access.

I am now researching a way to rename it back through some other approach, since the UI blocks you from naming the column back to "Name".

So, to answer your question:  Don't do it!

Comment: As you wrote, you have changed the display name of the Title site column of the parent content type (I assume it was the Item content type on the root web of the site collection). Of course it has consequences on your site collection. But changing the display name of the Title column of a content type (DisplayName property of FieldLink) that does not have dozens of other content types inherited from it (for example a content type bound to a list) is usually quite common. You can assess the hidden user list via $web.SiteUserInfoList from PowerShell and change things back from code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any issues. I've done this myself several times and have not encountered any problems.

Comment: Agree with Rob, I've never had an issue - I've also used the RemoveFieldRef directive in Content Types that inherit from item to remove it.

Comment: I agree. FieldRef and RemoveFieldRef shouldn't cause any problems. I heard, if you change the Fieldname itself, it can cause the problem, that you can't change it back because the old name is "reserved", maybe thats what you read about?